# Каланча или башня

Tags: этимология, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Почему **каланча** называется каланчой?
Чем она отличается (возможно, технически) от обычной башни?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

КАЛАНЧА. Высокая наблюдательная башня пожарной части.

БАШНЯ [от итал. bastia - крепость]. Высокое узкое архитектурное или инженерное сооружение (круглой, четырёхгранной или многогранной формы) различного назначения. В старину имели важное оборонное значение, служили местом заточения и пыток; широко используются в культовой и гражданской архитектуре (характерны для готического стиля и стиля модерн).

Этимология

Сначала была башня: 16 век, из польского bashta и русский суффикс НЯ, ранее существовало заимствование bashta. Каланча появилась в 18 веке от арабского "кала" - маленькая крепость.

Comment: Интересно,  почему   наблюдательная  башня  пожарной  части  стала  называться  именно  каланчой,  а  не  вышкой,  допустим.  Может  конструкция  заимствовалась  вместе  с  названием  и  назначением ?

Comment: Черных пишет, что слово "каланча" распространилось в середине 18 века, когда их стали строить над  зданиями полицейских управлений. Однако это слово встречалось в языке и раньше, но в значении крепость: "взял турецкую каланчу". Скорее всего, здесь исходная форма - калача, Н - вставное.

Comment: Может  обязательным  атрибутом  турецкой  крепости  была  такая  башня.  Общее  значение  закрепилось  в  другом  языке  впоследствии  только  за  частью  инженерно-строительного  ансамбля.

Comment: Тогда это будет  языковая метафора - перенос по смежности: крепость с обязательной башней - сама башня.

Comment: Дались вам Турки. Каланча у них это витая спиральная лестница. А вообще Каланча в позднем значении -маленький гарнизон. Застава по нашему.

Comment: @Vera, Что-то мне сдаётся, что конструктивно они отличаются следующим, и даже не только конструктивно, но и функционально:  
• Башня - хорошо укрепленное сооружение, выполняющее оборонительное и сдерживающее противника функции. Сооружение в большей степени военное. Строилось обычно по периметру населённых пунктов, стен городов или по периметру крепостей.

Comment: • Каланча - обычное, в большей степени гражданское сооружение, в виде башневидной постройки, но с менее милитаристскими целями. Практически не укреплённое от военного воздействия. Строилось обычно наоборот в черте города. Ближе к густонаселённым его частям. И носило скорее информационный функционал. По типу - смотровой вышки.

Comment: Так,  полисемия  и  в  турецком  присутствует.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю, что "каланча" - это тюркское слово, образованное от арабского. И - да, это каланча - это не любая башня, а именно пожарная. Правда, не знаю, можно ли отнести это название к привычным по нашему детству водонапорным башням.
А вот типичная каланча:

[image]

Comment: Мне кажется, что каланча - это скорее конструкция, чем функционал. Поэтому я тоже в некотором затруднении насчет водонапорной башни.  
  
Но я, собственно, хотел офтопом спросить, откуда эта "типичная" родом? Что-то до боли знакомое и родное, а сообразить не могу.

Comment: Маяк это напоминает. Колонна. Коломна. Стоит наблюдатель наверху, чуть огонь увидел  и орет - пожар.  Не даром в колокол при пожаре били, наверняка был на башне, потом и переносной. На маяках тоже в колокол били. А уж потом ревун.
Вообще колокольный звон далеко слышен, даже в тумане.

Answer (score 0):

Я откопал!!! Ошибка стоившая мне нескольких дней поиска. КаланЬча . Это не здание - это профессия!!!   Когда то этих людей звали Звездочет(ы). Родоначальники науки об окружающем мире метеорологии!!! Инженеры проектировщики зиккуратов. Это потом военные технологии придут в науку. И падишахи воины заменят падишахов просветителей. Каланча ведь стоит не просто так. Нужно знать куда и как дует ветер(и это только малая часть .)Эх бездна бездн... Это и есть пер аспера по ступеням которой идут к астра..

Comment: Поделитесь,  где  откопали.  Нам  тоже  интересно.

Answer (score 0):

Каждая  каланча - башня.  Это  ясно.  И  назначение  её  в  России  понятно.  А  что  у  нас  в  России  называется  "обычной"  башней ?  Кремлёвские  башни ?  Крепостные  башни ?  Просто  сильно  вытянутые  в  высоту  сооружения ?   Первые -  в  средине  18  века  уже  не  строят.  Вторые -  не  специфичны.  В  период  русско - турецких  войн  такая  конструкция,  как  турецкая  каланча,  известна  многим.  Понадобилось  такое  сооружение   в  русских  городах  -  заимствовали  вместе  с  названием.  Она  и  отличалась  от  других  разновидностей  башен  и  пропорциями  и  назначением.

Answer (score -1):

Все бы хорошо, да только башни у нас из колен строят, они Многоярусные. Колокол+ колени=колокольня.

В таджикском языке минарет, башня, вышка - манораи, манораҳо, манора  соответственно, выдают свое предназначение, оттуда человек орет. Колокола нет.
У башни русской всегда головка имеется, купол, крыша,  башка.
В Европе, как правило, это отсутствует.
Вот они  безбашенные: [http://www.skyscrapercity.com/showthread.php?s=e31e5d0961259c4281523f65e9669312&t=1511673&page=16ъ](http://www.skyscrapercity.com/showthread.php?s=e31e5d0961259c4281523f65e9669312&t=1511673&page=16%D1%8A)
И еще пример: Бастилия.

[image]

И в  латинском алфавите нет русских щипящих, они автоматом заменялись на двух-, трехбуквенные сочетания: баш - будет звучать bast, именно таким образом крепость в шведском стала fästning.
изба в монгольском - байшин (дом). А у нас осталась избушка, из башки без чертежей ума хватало.

А у латинян  фашина - связка дров, чтоб хоть подступиться к башням, Faschinen
и хитрое замечание,   Замена  Б-В-f типична в немецком, а еще и s - готическое в.

Comment: Вы привели в пример в сравнении башни и с каланчой Бастилию? Но разве это не крепость?
Это как сравнимать отличие шлюпки от лодки, а в пример привести параход!